# Why is the result when executing this C MPI application for Pi approximation always the same?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, pi, srand

This C MPI application for Pi approximation always prints out the same result per problem size, which is the number of random generated dots (`npts`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int myid,nprocs;

  double PI25DT = 3.141592653589793238462643;

  long long npts = 1e10;

  long i,mynpts;

  long double f,sum,mysum;
  long double xmin,xmax,x;

  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&nprocs);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myid);

  if (myid == 0) {
    mynpts = npts - (nprocs-1)*(npts/nprocs);
  } else {
    mynpts = npts/nprocs;
  }

  mysum = 0.0;
  xmin = 0.0;
  xmax = 1.0;

  srand(myid);  

  for (i=0; i<mynpts; i++) {
    x = (long double) rand()/RAND_MAX*(xmax-xmin) + xmin;
    mysum += 4.0/(1.0 + x*x);
  }

  MPI_Reduce(&mysum,&sum,1,MPI_LONG_DOUBLE,MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  if (myid == 0) {
    f = sum/npts;
    printf("PI calculated with %lld points = %.16f \n",npts,f);
    printf("Error is: %.16f \n",fabs(f-PI25DT));
  }

  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

This is the output. I think the result should differ a bit for each run of the application. I execute it on a cluster with 128 nodes.

```
$ mpicc pi.c -o /mnt/cluster_128/pi
$ mpirun -np 128 --hostfile hosts_4cores_128.mpi  /mnt/cluster_128/pi 
PI calculated with 10000000000 points = 3.1415901444578158 
Error is: 0.0000025091319773 
$ mpirun -np 128 --hostfile hosts_4cores_128.mpi  /mnt/cluster_128/pi 
PI calculated with 10000000000 points = 3.1415901444578158 
Error is: 0.0000025091319773 
$ mpirun -np 128 --hostfile hosts_4cores_128.mpi  /mnt/cluster_128/pi 
PI calculated with 10000000000 points = 3.1415901444578158 
Error is: 0.0000025091319773 
$ mpirun -np 128 --hostfile hosts_4cores_128.mpi  /mnt/cluster_128/pi 
PI calculated with 10000000000 points = 3.1415901444578158 
Error is: 0.0000025091319773
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeding the PRNG here:

```
srand(myid);
```

`myid` is a value set by your call to `MPI_Comm_rank()` and you're only interested in results for `myid == 0`, so this is always the same value. Seeding the same value yields the same sequence of "random" numbers.

Use the common idiom of seeding instead:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

[...]

srand(time(0));
```

Comment: It's an output from `MPI_Comm_rank`

Comment: @WeatherVane is it any good for seeding? Then I'll delete this answer ...

Comment: No, because the code only prints the results when `if (myid == 0) `

Answer (score 1):

Your code only prints any result when `if (myid == 0)` which shows your RNG seed is useless.

I suggest

```
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
```

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers already point to the right direction, but I think their explanation is not completely right.

The problem is, as already said, on the RNG seed. You are using `myid` as a seed for `srand`, which is always a number between `0` and `N-1` (being `N` the number of ranks, i.e. the number you pass to `mpiexec -np N executable` command). This is deterministic: it does not change for different executions.

Therefore, all the N processes are going to create the same set of seeds, and the generated random numbers are going to be the same for the same numbers of processes:

- For a single process (N=1): seed value is always 0
- For five processes (N=5): seed values are always 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 in each process. And so on.

The `MPI_Reduce` collective gathers all the partial results from each process (which yield the same values due to the random numbers being the same) and prints the grand sum in the root process (`myid=0`). The fact that the process with `myid` prints the result or not does not matter, as there are other N-1 processes with different `myid` values that contribute to the final result that is being print.

Small example for 2 processes, with `myid`:

- **Rank 0**: `srand(0)`, computes partial sum (`mysum`), accumulates others processes' partial sums in `sum` variable (you specify `0` as the root process in `MPI_Reduce` 7th argument. Prints the result (`myid==0` is `true`).
- **Rank 1**: `srand(1)`, computes partial sum (`mysum`) sends it to `MPI_Reduce` root process (`0`). Does not print the result (`myid==0` is `false`).

The most important thing you need to understand with MPI is that you typically execute a single program with multiple processes, and each of these processes get a different *environment* (output argument of `MPI_Comm_rank`).